# Monitor turns on when computer accessed remotely by Remote Desktop user

Tags: windows-7, remote-desktop, power-management

I am running Windows 7, service pack 1, 64-bit, NVIDIA GeForce 8800 GT. I used `Power Options` to configure the monitor to turn off after 10 minutes of inactivity. This works fine when I use the computer locally, but when I connect to the computer remotely using Remote Desktop two things happen:

1. The monitor turns on when the remote user logs in (bad!)
2. The monitor remains on even after the use disconnects (bad!)

Note that the user is closing Remote Desktop without logging off.

**How do I prevent Windows from turning the monitor on when the computer is accessed remotely?**

---

**Update**: I reconfigured the display to turn off after 1 minute of inactivity (previously it was 10 minutes). What I see is the display turning off, then turning on a few minutes later. The monitor then turns off a minute later and this process repeats every couple of minutes.

`powercfg -requests` after a wake-up returns:

```
DISPLAY:
None.

SYSTEM:
[SERVICE] \Device\HarddiskVolume2\Windows\System32\svchost.exe (CryptSvc)

AWAYMODE:
None.
```

`powercfg -lastwake` returns:

```
Wake History Count - 0
```

`powercfg -devicequery wake_armed` returns:

```
HID-compliant mouse
Microsoft USB Natural Ergonomic Keyboard 4000 (Mouse and Keyboard Center)
HID Keyboard Device (002)
```

`powercfg -energy` didn't return anything I considered meaningful.

The only other clue is that I've noticed my mouse batteries are low. Perhaps the mouse is sending random activity signals to the system? **Is there a way for me to look up who woke up the display last?**

Comment: Does the monitor turn off after 10 minutes of inactivity even while the user is logged in/the remote user logs out?

Comment: @chipperyman573, the display turns off (while the remote user is logged in) but turns on at some later time for no apparent reason.

Comment: Does anyone know the current behavior on Windows 10? Does RDP (or NoMachine) turn on/wake the remote monitor during a remote session?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my particular case, installing Logitech SetPoint (drivers) seemed to have resolved the problem. I suspect the built-in drivers were outdated and waking up the monitor.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's on old question, but I had the same problem and found why it is happening. I found out that it's "by design" on this website https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/design/device-experiences/modern-standby-wake-sources

> Remote Desktop can turn on the display on the target system.

And during my testing, I found out that during Remote Desktop connection monitor indeed wakes up, but it goes to sleep after X minutes, and those X minutes are that which you configure in Power Options "turn monitor off after X minutes of inactivity" (or something like that, I don't have English Windows).